# When I run 'npx cap sync' the terminal just hangs

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, cocoapods, capacitor

I run the following commands on my M1 Macbook in my terminal to prepare a build for my phone to test it on xcode. First I do `ionic build` which works fine. Then I run `npx cap sync` which works until it gets to this line:

⠙ update ios [info] Found 5 Cordova plugins for ios:
com.adjust.sdk@4.30.0
cordova-plugin-email-composer@0.10.0
cordova-plugin-globalization@1.11.0
cordova-plugin-ionic@5.5.2
cordova-sqlite-storage@6.0.0
⠹ Updating iOS native dependencies with pod install

Then the terminal just hangs, there's no error message. I've tried leaving it but nothing seems to happen. I experience this issue regularly which is frustrating as I need to test my code on my device.

I've tried running `sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi` and then `arch -x86_64 pod install` in ios/App which both run fine but doesn't seem to fix the above issue.

Sometimes if I delete the ios folder, run `npx cap sync` then reinstall the ios folder using `npx cap add ios`. I'll be able to get a build on my phone but this only works sporadically.

I'm looking for a consistent solution to the problem.

Comment: I've had this issue for a few months now when building for ios. The only solutions I found were the ones you listed above (pinning the issue on using an M1 mac) but, like you, they only worked sporadically.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is an ionic project one other thing you can try is to run ionic sync command:
`ionic cap sync`

Comment: I've tried this too, but get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to reinstall Xcode and delete all Xcode related files. It still takes time to sync but now works consistently.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found since I asked this that moving to a more powerful macbook pro with more RAM actually solved the issue and my terminal no longer hangs. I think my old machine just couldn't handle doing the builds and xcode with the juice it required. Occasionally it will throw an error along the lines of cocoapods but running sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi and then arch -x86_64 pod install in ios/App solves this.